# Solving a simple non-homogeneous system

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Solving $Ax=b$ where $$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 1&2 \\ 
 1&3 
\end{bmatrix},$$ and $$b=\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
3\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}.$$ I am supposed to solve for $x$.

I am trying to solve by Gaussian elimination but I am getting a contradiction where $x_{1}=-3$,$x_{2}=1$. But the first row of the matrix shows that $x_{1}+x_{2}=2$, but I am getting $x_{1}+x_{2}=-2$

Comment: You either misread the problem or the system really is inconsistent and has no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, if you are asked to solve an equation, the possibility is allowed that there is no solution.  In this case you should just state that there is no solution, and give reasons.

The reason you have given is fine, but perhaps even easier,
$$x_1+x_2=2,\ x_1+3x_2=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2x_1+4x_2=2
  \quad\Rightarrow\quad x_1+2x_2=1$$
which contradicts the second equation.

Comment: That sounds completely different and you probably should ask it as a new question.  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "the plane above equations create" and it would probably be a good idea to post the question exactly as you saw it in your textbook/course/whatever.